# Can't display properly filtered Region of Interest on Google Earth Engine Map

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, display

I am trying to display a ROI (region of interest) on the GEE map. I am getting pretty odd outputs like this:

[image]

Code that generated this image is down below:

```
var geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-74.17301042227143, 41.01676815108097],
      [-75.15079362539643, 40.93797200093739],
      [-74.50260026602143, 40.3084072747414],
      [-73.63468034414643, 40.559275861105796]]]);

var landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")

Map.centerObject(geometry)

var area = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);

var image = ee.Image((landsat)
    .filterBounds(area)
    .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
    .select(['B[1-7]'])
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first());
var filteredimage = image
//.clip(area)
Map.addLayer(filteredimage, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.5, gamma: 2}, 'Better L8 Image');
```

If I uncomment the `.clip(area)` line, I get only the intersection of these two chunks. But what I want is to show only the red section. And show all of it. From what I understand is the these square pictures are the raw pictures of the satellite. But how can I crop an image out of two or more different satellite images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `.first()`, you are asking for only the *first* (here, least cloudy) image from the `LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA` that matches your other filters. Generally, when you want images from an area, you should use an operator like `.mosaic()` (prefer the *last* available image, but on a pixel-by-pixel basis — useful when sorted by date) or `.median()` (take the median of all images).

```js
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var image = ee.Image((landsat)
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .median());
var filteredimage = image.clip(geometry);
Map.addLayer(filteredimage, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.5, gamma: 2}, 'Better L8 Image');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c1f26be1cc2581247f4265894751e7a4

I've also simplified your code a couple of ways:

- There is no need for `var area = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);` — none of what you're doing requires a collection.
- There is no need for `.select(['B[1-7]'])` — the band selection you are doing in `addLayer` suffices to control which pixels get computed, so the `.select()` is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i still want to ask this. I want to make a timelapse about vegetation change throughout the years. It will include about 300 satellite images.  If i keep the band selection option (Red Green Blue NIR) will my code be faster?

Comment: @user9279225 I am not sure whether it will make any difference at all, but certainly not a large one.